# combination of using Google Bigtable and Cloud Pubsub occasionally hangs

Tags: flask, gunicorn, google-cloud-pubsub, gevent, google-cloud-bigtable

I've made a web API application using Gunicorn(Gevent) + Flask chain.

When It received a data, it read rows from 5 different tables in Bigtable with singleton pattern then do a cpu bound task.

After that, It publishes a message to Pubsub.

But the problem is sometimes It hangs forever right before the loop.

```
data = {}
for bigtable in five_bigtables:
    rows = bigtable.read_rows(row_key)
    print('reading rows start')
    for row in rows:
        data[row.row_key] = row.cells[column_family][column_qualifier][0]


publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)
publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
```

So I can see the "reading rows start" on console and stop working.

And If i commented out a function that publish a message to Pubsub, It works totally fine.

The version of the packages

```
flask==2.0.3
gevent==21.12.0
google-cloud-bigtable==2.5.1
google-cloud-pubsub==2.9.0
grpcio-status==1.44.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

The gunicorn configs are these

```
worker_class = 'gevent'
preload_app = False
```

How I can reproduce the hang is that I used Apache ab testing

```
ab -n 10000 -c 200 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_url"
```

after some requests It shows.

```
Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
apr_pollset_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
Total of 139 requests completed
```

Any comment or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe read_rows is taking too long? You can set a deadline for that operation via the `retry` method parameter: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigtable/blob/59087c8316b4326c2ac6b4797bec57acba0e0792/google/cloud/bigtable/table.py#L604

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried that retry options with deadline for 10 seconds. It stops getting rows after setting the deadline but the application should get that value from Bigtable then it can continue to process.

Comment: If `read_rows` is failing after the deadline, it means its not able to find the rows in BigTable or perhaps the backend operation took too long. Are you certain rows with those keys exist in your BigTable?

Comment: @PradNelluru Yes I'm pretty sure that the row_key exists cause in the table I set only wrote the three row keys there and It's hard to believe the backend operation took too long since there are only 3 row keys. But a cell in each row key has almost 10 MB data which means 30 MB data in a table. Does it make an effect to read the rows?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the bigtable service in cloud console? And is it possible to reproduce this using the bigtable emulator (gcloud beta emulators bigtable)?

Comment: how about adding some more prints like this

~~~
<!-- language: python -->
data = {}
for bigtable in five_bigtables:
    print('reading rows call')
    rows = bigtable.read_rows(row_key)
    print('reading rows streaming')
    for row in rows:
        data[row.row_key] = row.cells[column_family][column_qualifier][0]

print('reading rows done')
~~~

Comment: @IgorBernstein I've never seen any error in the bigtable service in cloud console. ok. I will try the emulator to reproduce the hanging.

Comment: @JohnFremlin I tried setting logs on inside loop and before loop. but it still stuck there.